# How to remove ?q= from URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I understand that `.htaccess` URL re-write questions have been asked a number of times however, I am really struggling to get these two things working in combination.

My site takes the following url and performs a wildcard search

`http://www.localhost:8888/exercises/exercise?q=overehead%20squat&`

I am using the following rule to remove all the `%20` spaces to give me:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Gives: `http://www.localhost:8888/exercises/exercise?q=Overhead-Squat`

The last thing I would like to do is remove the ?q= so the URL looks like this:

`http://www.localhost:8888/exercises/exercise/overehead-squat`

It is not essential to make it lowercase, however it is desirable.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a directory called "excercise" and place your code file in it (name it `index.php`), and place this `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) index\.php?q=$1
```

Comment: Thanks Uri, I'm using Craft CMS so don't have the usual luxury of putting index.php in its own directory. Is it possible to find every instance of /exercises?q=query and replace it with /exercises/query.

Comment: I'm still strugging with this - this is giving me the correct re-written URL however it is not performing the query for me. 
`RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "(.*(?:^|&))q=([^&]*)&?(.*)&?$"
RewriteRule "(.*)"            "%1$1/%2/?" [PT]`

Comment: Well currently it doesn't work at all... the code I have posted above is nothing like yours? So currently it doesn't solve the issue - therefore its not the correct answer or give a very good explanation of what it is doing. Appreciate your help - however this doesn't answer the question.